# Show/ Hide specific table row in MVC view with onclick button and id

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, html-table, hide, show

I want to show a row in my table to edit the object in a row above if I click on the edit button there. 
The table looks like:

```
   <table id="Table">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>@Html.Label("Name", "Name")</th>
                        <th>@Html.Label("ID", "ID")</th>
                            <th>@Html.Label("OtherFields", "Other fields")</th>
                        <th></th>
                        <th></th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                @for (int i = 0; i < Model.models.Count(); i++)
                {<tr>
                    @Html.Hidden("Name", @Model.Name)</td>
                    <td>@Html.Label("ID", @Model.ID)</td>
                    <td>@Html.Label("OtherFields", @Model.OtherFields)</td>
                     <td> <button type="button"name="ShowEditButton" value="@i" id="EditButton" onclick="ShowEdit(@i)">Edit</button>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <button name="deleteButton" value="@i" class="formbutton" id="DeleteButton" onclick="DoNotPrompt()">Delete</button></td>
                </tr>
                    <tr id="Details(@i)" style="display:none;">
                        <td colspan="4">..........</td>
                        <td>
                            <button name="acceptButton" value="@i" class="formbutton" id="AcceptButton" onclick="SaveEdit(@i)">Accept</button></td>
                    </tr> }
            </table>
```

and my jQuery method is

```
        function ShowEdit(i) {
        $('#Details('+i+')').style.display = 'table-row';
    }
```

I also try it with `hidden:"hidden"` for the row and `show()` in the Javascript.
Also I checked it with debugger and the method get called but it doesn't display anything to me. In my application the row with the data is much bigger and cause several one-to-many relationships and lookup tables it would get very confusing to edit it in the row it was displayed. So I would like to give a user the opportunity to edit it just in the row below the information. The `AcceptButton` then would send it to the server. Can anybody help me? Could it be that it isn't possible what I try to do?

**Problem solved:** I had to remove the brackets from the `id`s and replace them with `_` to make it run

Answer (score 0):

Not sure but you are not calling the desired function:

1. `onclick="ShowEdit(@i)"`
2. `onclick="DoNotPrompt()"`
3. `onclick="SaveEdit(@i)"`

and your function is `"ShowMutationEdit()"`:

```
function ShowMutationEdit(i) {
    $('#MutationDetails('+i+')').style.display = 'table-row';
}
```

#### Just saw your updates:

*`In my application the row with the data is much bigger`* So you are using IDs for each button beacuse it is in loop and there are many duplicates in terms of id attribute.

```
function ShowEdit(i) {
    $('#Details('+i+')')[0].style.display = 'table-row';
}//---------------------^^^--------------------try adding this
```

and this:

```
function ShowEdit(i) {
    $('#Details('+i+')').show();
}//---------------------^^^^^^^--------------------try adding this
```

Comment: I edited it to make it clear. The specific button is `<td> <button type="button"name="ShowEditButton" value="@i" id="EditButton" onclick="ShowEdit(@i)">Edit</button>` and the method is called. I try it with debugger and also use `alert()` to be sure that the right method gets hit.

Comment: Your right i forgot to give the buttons unique ids, i instead used the parameter in the method `ShowEdit(@i)` to define where to change but i have now also change the buttons to unique ids.  `<button type="button"name="ShowEditButton" value="@i" id="EditButton(@i)" onclick="ShowEdit(@i)">Edit</button>`. Then i changed the jquery method like in your example but it don´t change anything. The first with `show()` i also already tried.